# Installed Electrum does not start and now Electrum-Ltc no longer works - update python/urllib3?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, python, pip

I Installed electrum following the instructions from https://electrum.org/#download

Install dependencies:
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip

Install Electrum:
sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.1.1/Electrum-3.1.1.tar.gz

OS is linux mint 17

When I click the electrum icon through the applications menu nothing happens.
I have electrum-ltc installed and it was working. Since installing electrum it will not run.

If I try to start it through the command line I get the following error:

$ ./electrum

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.7.1) or chardet (2.2.1) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Error: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'. Try 'sudo pip install <module-name>'
```

Trying to update urllib3 and chardet I get these errors:

$ sudo pip install urllib3

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Cleaning up...
```

$ pip install --upgrade urllib3

```
Downloading/unpacking urllib3 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/63/cb/6965947c13a94236f6d4b8223e21beb4d576dc72e8130bd7880f600839b8/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1c11e1c80371cc4e89911071010a98d1
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB): 132kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: urllib3
  Found existing installation: urllib3 1.7.1
    Not uninstalling urllib3 at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back urllib3; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3'
```

How can I update urllib3?

Or does the problem have something to do with the dependencies I installed?

"Install dependencies:
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip"

Electrum-ltc was working fine before I installed the dependencies above for Electrum (btc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two python installations in your system, `python2.7` and `python3.4`. The `pip` command refers to the package manager for `python2.7`, so when you issue `pip install urllib3`, you're trying to install/update the `urllib3` package for the wrong version of Python - use `pip3` to install/update packages for Python 3:

```
$ pip3 install chardet urllib3 --upgrade --user
```

---

Btw, I prefer not to call `sudo pip`/`sudo pip3` because some python packages are managed by `apt` (like `pip` itself, `setuptools` or `requests`), so if you have first installed

```
$ apt install python3-setuptools
```

and then start to `sudo pip3 install` packages, sooner or later you'll break stuff because `setuptools` is declared as a dependency by many python packages and you will accidentally overwrite `python3-setuptools` installation. It's safer to `sudo apt install` and if `apt` does not provide the package you need or provides an old version of it, then `pip install --user` it.